# Create visualforce page to show time line using highcharts in salesforce

Tags: highcharts, salesforce, visualforce, apex, timeline.js

Please help me how to use highcharts with salesforce. I want to show timeline in visualforce page.

Comment: Please add your code, if you want any help.

Comment: Could you attach any mockup? It should look like [gantt](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart) chart?

Comment: Want to create simile-widgets timeline in salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in specific you would like to know about highcharts? These two links might be helpful:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/09/using-the-salesforce-analytics-api-on-a-visualforce-page.html

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_charting_example.htm